# How can I make a Sequence to iterate over all the ancestors (superviews) from a UIView up the view hierarchy to the root?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I'd like for `UIView` to have a property that returns a sequence of all the ancestors of the view up the hierarchy. That would be useful for purposes like finding the nearest one that matches a particular type:

```
let tableView = cell.ancestors.first(where: { $0 is UITableView })
```

What's a nice way of implementing that `ancestors` property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `sequence(first:next:)` function, from the *Swift Standard Library*, an even shorter solution is possible as well:

```swift
extension UIView {
    var ancestors: AnySequence<UIView> {
        return AnySequence<UIView>(
            sequence(first: self, next: { $0.superview }).dropFirst())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a type that conforms to [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence) and add a property returning it in an extension. A `Sequence` normally needs a `makeIterator()` method that returns a type that conforms to [`IteratorProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/iteratorprotocol), but in this case we can make the sequence act as its own iterator and use one type for both, which makes things very simple:

**Swift 3:**

```
struct AncestorSequenceIterator: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    var current: UIView
    mutating func next() -> UIView? {
        guard let next = current.superview else { return nil }
        current = next
        return next
    }
}

extension UIView {
    var ancestors: AncestorSequenceIterator {
        return AncestorSequenceIterator(current: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: If the only use of the `ancestors` property is to find a parent of a certain type then your solution is inefficient. You build the whole list of ancestors but then you really only iterate the first few (typically) to find the matching ancestor. Why walk the entire superview list first, then go back and only iterate the first few to find the match? Why not eliminate that unnecessary first step and just do the much shorter (typically) second step? Could be accomplished with a simply extension to UIView. Your `ancestors` property might have its uses but this purpose isn't one of them.

Comment: @rmaddy This doesn't build a whole list of ancestors – it merely creates an iterator that can iterate directly up the view hierarchy. Using `first(where:)` with it will short-circuit upon finding the first match that satisfies the predicate. If you wanted to build a list of ancestors, you would have to say something like `Array(someView.ancestors)`.

Comment: @Hamish Oh, good point. That negates my whole comment. Never mind, move along. Nothing to see here. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create extension and return IteratorProtocol to be able to do first(where:) comparison like so,

```
extension UIView {

    var ancestors: AnyIterator<UIView> {
        var current: UIView = self

        return AnyIterator<UIView> {
            guard let parent = current.superview else {
                return nil
            }
            current = parent
            return parent

        }
    }
}
```

Since AnyIterator itself conforms to Sequence, the statement that you showed above should work fine.

```
let tableView = cell.ancestors.first(where: { $0 is UITableView })
```

Answer (score 1):

Paulo Mattos's implementation is good, but for your specific use, you probably want something like this:

```
extension UIView {
    func nearestAncestor<T: UIView>(ofType type: T.Type) -> T? {
        if let me = self as? T { return me }
        return superview?.nearestAncestor(ofType: type)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
guard let tableView = cell.nearestAncestor(ofType: UITableView.self) else { return }
// tableView at this point is type UITableView
```

Comment: That's a great solution to the specific problem, but in this case I wanted to see if it could be solved in a more general and functional way :)